# Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 403 in Webapp

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, web-applications, geolocation

I am using `Geolocation.watchPosition()` and I get the following error on callback

> Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned
>   error code 403.

This seems to be only happening in chrome desktop browser. firefox seems to be fine. This is also just started happening today, I have never come across this error before within my web app using the `Geolocation.watchPosition()`.

Update: bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=753242

Comment: did you find out why this happened? Just started happening to me now, worked all the time. Then after a minute it worked again. Maybee google server was down?

Comment: I've just started getting it too. Been working on a Chrome app and in the past 15 minutes started to get it every time I load the app. The geo location stuff isn't working, it's defaulting to my debug lat/long.

Comment: Getting this too since a few weeks. Just guessing - could it be the name of the Wifi changed I / you are connected to and Google location service has no idea how to deal with the new Wifi name?

Comment: known bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=753242

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me too. I had to enable location services on my Mac.

Answer (score 3):

After looking for an answer, I think there is something wrong with Google

I tried it with developers.google site

**Safari**: worked
**Google Chrome**: failed

[image: Current location in developers.google also not working]

Comment: Yep, there is only Chrome has the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a chrome issue, to get around it you have to check your [developer dashboard](https://console.developers.google.com) and make sure that your API key has no warnings.

Also, you need to make sure that the proper usage restrictions are in place for the development phase:

> This key is unrestricted. To prevent unauthorized use and quota theft, restrict your key.
> Key restriction lets you specify which web sites, IP addresses, or apps can use this key.

More information can be found [here](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=en_US).

Comment: I'm experiencing this now. It was working 2 hours ago and now I can't figure out why it's throwing `Returned error code 403` I looked at my API dashboard and the `Traffic` nor `Error` analytics are empty. Looks like my request didn't even reach Google. Where should we look for the "warnings" you mentioned?

Comment: Hey @JohnnyQ , you should test this behavior on different browsers to make sure that the 403 is actually coming from chrome, head over to console.developers.google.com , your dashboard should show the state of the requests that get to the server.

Comment: This was the problem for me, setting some restrictions in the console fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might be the answer you're looking for.
403 means you've reached your daily limit when using googleapis,  I am getting the same problem on all my google software.

Source:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

Comment: OP is using [GeoLocation API](https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/#watchposition-method). This isn't a Google thing, it's W3C web standard. Pretty sure you don't need Google API credentials to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I reset my location permission to ***Ask(default)*** in chrome and after reload ***Allow*** the location and boom... , its worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart Chrome (Force Quit), and it will work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is might be an issue with google map API. I was also using google map API yesterday and it was not working as it should be. And then i started using this free plugin and it worked for me like a charm.
http://www.geoplugin.com/

Comment: Maybe there is an issue, but the question is from 5 months ago.

Comment: yeah i agree. maybe there is an issue with google API. but i got the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where it is not working on Chrome. And then I found this link
https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/3j8ipj/anyone_else_had_issues_with_the_html5_geolocation/

According to one of Reddit user, you need set to enableHighAccuracy to true. The code looks something like this

```
//Get current location    
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                position => {
                    console.log(position.coords);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log("Error: ", error)
                },{ enableHighAccuracy: true });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I blocked google to get my geolocation. After Delete it from black list I got response.
[chrome://settings/content/location](https://chrome://settings/content/location)
*Not allowed to see your location*
if still not worked ,you may need have VPN after all.