# Geolocation API is available and enabled but does not give the coordinates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

I'm creating an app where i need to get access to user's coordinates to display their location on the map. I'm using react for that matter and the problem is the success callback never gets called and I can't get access to the coordinates.
does anyone know what might cause this behavior?
here's my code.

```
const Routing = (props) => {

const success = (position) => {
  console.log(position);
};

useEffect(() => {
  const geo = navigator.geolocation;
  if (!geo) {
    return;
  }
  geo.getCurrentPosition(success);
}, []);

return (
  <div className="map">
    <MapContainer />
  </div>
);
};
```

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint inside `useEffect`?

Comment: I'm getting  "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received." error.

Comment: That will be the reason why! And seems like you're not alone in this :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137594/network-location-provider-at-https-www-googleapis-com-returned-error-code

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.geolocation` has multiple drawbacks: it is not always available; it requires the user's consent; while doing so it displays an annoying pop-up; it uses approximation methods that are inconsistent and may give unexpected results; it required HTTPS, so it's hard to test on your local development server.

Do you have the possibility to test an alternative, see if it works for you and if you don't have error anymore? I suggest a realtime API such as [Abstract IP Location](https://www.abstractapi.com/ip-geolocation-api) which is free.

You call the API omitting the `ip_address` parameter, so it returns the geolocation for the device making the API call. In the response, you get the `longitude` and `latitude` fields you can use to display the map's marker.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you facing to an error ?

```
geo.getCurrentPosition(success, () => console.log('Error happened !'));
```

Comment: you're right, i'm getting "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received." error. I searched for it and didn't find any solution.